# How to insert integers number to doubly linked list from a text file?

Tags: c++

This's program will display the integers numbers from the text file

1 2 3 4 5 6

and ask the user to

1. Add a number "
2. Delete a number from the list
3. Show the list.

Can someone help me to implement the following step:

1.How to insert the integers numbers from the text file to the doubly linked list.

2.if the user added a number, the number should be added to the text file.

3- if the user delete a number, the number should be deleted from the text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
struct  node
{
    int number; 
    node *next; 
    node *prev; 
}*start;

class double_llist
{
public:
    bool isEmpty(node *head);
    char menu();
    void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number);
    void inser(node*&head, node*&last, int number);
    void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
    void showlist(node *current);
    int numIntElement(ifstream&x);
private:

};

int main() {

    string filename;
    cout << " Please enter the name of the file = "; 
    cin >> filename; 
    ifstream myfile; 
    myfile.open(filename); 
    if (!myfile.is_open()) {
        cout << endl << " failed to open file, check that it exists and you have access \n" << "\n" << endl; 

    }
    else if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        ifstream x;
        double_llist dl;
        dl.numIntElement(x); 
        int int1 = 0; 
        cout << " File exists \n";

        ////
        node * head = NULL;
        node *last = NULL;
        char choice;
        int number;
        do {
            choice = dl.menu();
            switch (choice)
            {
            case '1':
                cout << " Please enter number : ";
                cin >> number;
                dl.inser(head, last, number);
                break;
            case '2':
                dl.remove(head, last);
            case '3':
                dl.showlist(head);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != '4');
        {

        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
int double_llist::numIntElement(ifstream&x) {

    int n = 0;
    int m; 
    ifstream myfile("file.txt");
    int countsingfie = 0;

    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> n;
        //if (countsingfie == 0) {
        //  cout << "Error : file exist but no data " << endl;
        //}
        cout << "The numbers in the file are  " << n<< "" << endl;
    }
    return countsingfie;
}
bool double_llist::isEmpty(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
char double_llist::menu() {
    char choice; 
    cout << " Main Menu \n"; 
    cout << " 1 . Add a number \n";
    cout << " 2 . Delete a number from the list \n";
    cout << " 3 . Show the list \n"; 
    cout << " 4.  Exit \n";
    cin >> choice; 
    return choice;
}
void  double_llist::insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number) {
    node *temp = new node; 
    temp->number = number; 
    temp->next = NULL; 
    head = temp; 
    last = temp; 
}
void double_llist::inser(node*&head, node*&last, int number) {
    if (isEmpty(head)>0){
        insertAsFirstElement(head, last, number); 
    }
    else if (isEmpty(head) < 0)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a number above 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->number = number;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
void  double_llist::remove(node *&head, node *&last) {
    if (isEmpty(head)) {
        cout << " Sorry, The list is already empty \n"; 

    }
    else if (head == last)
    { 
        delete head; 
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL; 

    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head; 
        head = head->next; 
        delete temp; 
    }
}
void double_llist::showlist(node *current) {

    if (isEmpty(current)) {
        cout << " The list is empty \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " The list contains: \n "; 
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->number << endl; 
            current = current->next; 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not going to do your homework.

Comment: Nope, but here's a couple hints: 1. Implement the linked list separately and test the smurf out of it before using it with the rest of the code. You don't want to have to debug two pieces of code at the same time. 2. `while (!myfile.eof())` is not what you want. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong